# Why is the mac address that appears on my computer the same?

Tags: linux, mac-address, ifconfig

I use the 2 ethernet interface on the my system board, eth0 / eth1(usb to ethernet) like the followings.

```
root@E3-RDP:~# ifconfig
eth0 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr ae:a1:99:48:86:79
inet addr:10.10.0.171 Bcast:10.10.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::aca1:99ff:fe48:8679/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:532 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:18 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:36510 (36.5 KB) TX bytes:972 (972.0 B)
Interrupt:114

eth1 Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 00:0e:c6:87:72:01
inet addr:10.10.0.176 Bcast:10.10.0.255 Mask:255.255.255.0
inet6 addr: fe80::20e:c6ff:fe87:7201/64 Scope:Link
UP BROADCAST MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
RX packets:0 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
RX bytes:0 (0.0 B) TX bytes:94 (94.0 B)

lo Link encap:Local Loopback
inet addr:127.0.0.1 Mask:255.0.0.0
inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
UP LOOPBACK RUNNING MTU:16436 Metric:1
RX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
TX packets:44 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
collisions:0 txqueuelen:0
RX bytes:3336 (3.3 KB) TX bytes:3336 (3.3 KB)
```

When I check the system's mac address(eth0/eth1) on the pc, those address is the same like the following.

```
C:\Users\andy>arp -a IP MAC ADDR Type
10.10.0.1 90-9f-33-a8-20-14 dynamic
10.10.0.171 ae-a1-99-48-86-79 dynamic
10.10.0.176 ae-a1-99-48-86-79 dynamic
10.10.0.186 60-a4-4c-35-1a-dd dynamic
```

What should I check for this problem?

On my system the ping test(eth1) is failed.

```
root@E3-RDP:~# ping -I eth1 10.10.0.173
PING 10.10.0.173 (10.10.0.173) from 10.10.0.176 eth1: 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=5 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.10.0.176 icmp_seq=6 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 10.10.0.173 ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 0 received, +6 errors, 100% packet loss, time 6007ms
pipe 3
```

But the ping test by eth0 is ok.

```
root@E3-RDP:~# ping 10.10.0.173
PING 10.10.0.173 (10.10.0.173) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=1 ttl=128 time=2.40 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=2 ttl=128 time=0.327 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=3 ttl=128 time=0.459 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=4 ttl=128 time=0.727 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=5 ttl=128 time=0.403 ms
64 bytes from 10.10.0.173: icmp_seq=6 ttl=128 time=0.528 ms
^C
--- 10.10.0.173 ping statistics ---
6 packets transmitted, 6 received, 0% packet loss, time 5000ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.327/0.808/2.406/0.725 m
```

I think that the misrecognized mac address causes the ping test error(eth1).

And I want to implement the TCP client with the eth1.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`eth1` is not actually "usable". Don't get confused seeing "UP" in the command output with the actual state of your interface. You should be seeing `RUNNING`, just like the one in `eth0`.

```
UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1
```

IMO, commands such as `ip link show` and `ip addr show` provide clearer statuses of your network interfaces.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11679939/10637968) is a pretty good explanation of what's happening:

> `IFF_RUNNING` is supposed to reflect the operational status on a network
>   interface, rather than its administrative one. To provide an example,
>   an Ethernet interface may be brought `UP` by the administrator (e.g.
>   `ifconfig eth0 up`), but it will not be considered operational (i.e.
>   `RUNNING` as per RFC2863) if the cable is not plugged in.

Anyway, you need to recheck `eth1` as it appears to be down. `ip link show` would be a good start, but most likely it is currently not up or you have a cabling issue, esp. that you seem to have a physical machine.

Answer (score 0):

Both interfaces are in the same subnet 10.10.0.0/24. If you will check the routing table with `route -n` you will see 2 entries for the same subnet with different interfaces to use. The interface `eth0` would be before the `eth1` in the list. So even if packets are sent to this host via `eth1` IP address, the packets from this host  go back to this subnet via interface `eth0`. This is the reason why you see in the `arp` table same MAC address for both IP addresses.

You can try to use static routes or IP tables to do this, I guess.

To check interface status is possible with `ethtool` command.